# daml - how to fetch contract by key using Java bindings?

Tags: java, daml

I have Daml `template` with `key` defined. I'm building a Java service that tries to access Daml ledger using `bindings-rxjava`. The access pattern is a simple CRUD, and I'm stuck on R(ead) part.

I'm not able to find how to issue `fetchByKey` request using Java. I've looked through [examples](https://www.digitalasset.com/developers/examples) and see how it's done in `@daml/react` example [here](https://github.com/digital-asset/daml/blob/main/templates/create-daml-app/ui/src/components/MainScreen.tsx.template#L37). It uses JSON-API, and it's [/v1/fetch](https://docs.daml.com/json-api/index.html#fetch-contract-by-key) endpoint. But I don't see similar requests in [quickstart-java](https://github.com/digital-asset/daml/tree/main/templates/quickstart-java) and [ex-java-bindings](https://github.com/digital-asset/ex-java-bindings) repos. Also, both examples don't have a `template` with `key` defined.

The only working solution I can think of (based on the examples above) is to subscribe to `ActiveContractsClient.getActiveContracts` for my template, then store received contracts in DB and fetch by key from DB. But that sounds overly complicated comparing to JS examples.

Please, point me towards a working example for fetching by key using Java bindings. I'm okay with any JVM language (Java, Kotlin, Scala, Clojure, Groovy).

I'm also okay with calling JSON-API node from Java, but don't see any bindings for this. Am I stuck with manually constructing the JSON request in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"store received contracts in DB and fetch by key from DB" is how the JSON API provides the fetch-by-key functionality, when you have a DB configured. When you don't have a DB configured, it scans all of `getActiveContracts` until it finds a match. It does not have a quick-and-easy way to fetch by key itself, which is also why no such API exists in the Java bindings.

I recommend following the approach you've hit upon, with the qualifier that you should store ledger offset as well, and use the offset with the transaction stream to update the DB. (This is also how JSON API updates its database, rather than starting with `getActiveContracts` from scratch.)